# How to add a titlebar to a popover

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to replicate the appearance of the (no longer functional) [Degrees](http://www.degreesapp.com/) app, but I can't figure out the components used to make the title bar (highlighted here in red).

[image]

I've managed to get my app running as a menu bar agent, and I've wired up a popover to display a window view on click. But it's not quite right: my window's title bar disappears when in the popover, and the bar used in the Degrees app is wider than the one provided by the stock window control.

How might I mimic the appearance here? it just an ImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popover's don't show window title bar's as you've discovered.

Just add an NSView at the top of your window view and add a label for the title and a button for the "Done" button to create your top bar with desired height. Then add a horizontal line to the bottom of this title view and programmatically set the background color of its layer to whatever you desire. Offset all your other views by that bar height.

Basically:

```
[Window]
    [View]
        [View (Title Parent)]
            [NSTextField]
            [NSButton]
            [Horizontal Line]
        [Other Views]
```

For getting the gray background, in your `NSWindowController windowDidLoad`,

```
self.titleParentView.wantsLayer = YES
self.titleParentView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor grayColor].CGColor;
```

where `titleParentView` is an IBOutlet connected to the view you created above in the xib/storyboard

Comment: What about the appearance though, how can I achieve that? Meaning, the top view that you've described should have a slight grey gradient and then a darker line below to separate it from the main views. I'm brand new to Xcode and cocoa development, so forgive what is likely a beginner question.

Comment: Thanks, this was useful to get me started.